# How do I create an array of strings from an object where the values of individual keys are separate arrays of strings?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm trying to gather all errors in an `err` object and populate them into `this.errors` in order to display them.

**`err` object**:

```
err = {
  "name": [
    "Item name is required.",
    "Item name must be at least 4 chars"
  ],
  "rate": [
    "Item Rate is should be a number.",
    "Item rate should be between 10 and 1000"
  ],
  "category": ["Item Category is required"]
}
```

As you can see, err is an object where the values of individual keys are arrays of strings. To gather the error strings into a separate `this.errors` array, I could simply perform:

```
 if (err && err.number)  {
   err.number.forEach(e => {
     this.errors.push(e);
   });
 }

if (err && err.number)  {
   err.rate.forEach(e => {
     this.errors.push(e);
   });
 }

 if (err && err.number)  {
   err.category.forEach(e => {
     this.errors.push(e);
   });
 }
```

But I will need to repeat these lines of code in many places of my app.

I want to place these code in a functionl as:

```
populateErrors(err) {
    err.forEach(error => {
          this.errors.push(error);
    });
}

// and call it
this.populateErrors(err);
```

OR

```
populateErrors(err, keys[]) {
    err.forEach(error => {
          this.errors.push(err.keys[1]);
    });
    //...
}

// and call it
populateErrors(err, ['name', 'rate', 'category'])
```

and display them in my template:

```
<div class="row" *ngIf="errors && errors.length">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible">
                <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>
                <ol *ngFor="let err of errMsg">
                    <li>{{ err }}</li>
                </ol>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

What might the function look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `map` `reduce`.

```js
const err = {
  "name": [
    "Item name is required.",
    "Item name must be at least 4 chars"
  ],
  "rate": [
    "Item Rate is should be a number.",
    "Item rate should be between 10 and 1000"
  ],
  "category": ["Item Category is required"]
}

const arr = Object.keys(err)
  .map(k => err[k])
  .reduce((acumm, el) => acumm.concat(el), []);

console.log(arr)
```

We're combining `Object.keys` a native function that allow you to obtain the keys of an object with `map` and `reduce`.

`["name", "rate", "category"].map(...`

The `map` method creates a new array with the results of calling a function for every array element. So, I am returning the value of the property itself.

`[[ "Item name...", "Item name..." ], ["Item Rate...", "Item rate"], ["Item Category..."]].reduce(...`

The `reduce` method reduces the array to a single value. So I am concatenating all the values in a single array.

Comment: That a single line solution and works like a charm. Can you please explain it in brief, if you have time? Many thanks, man.

Comment: @anonym I'm sorry if my explanation is not really clear. Ask what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the map function coupled with a loop over the properties :

```
for (let prop in this.err) {
    this.errors = this.errors.join(
        this.err[prop].map(el => ({el}));
    );
}
```